# Where to add jQuery into PHP file

Tags: php, jquery

Here my jQuery

```
var emails = [
  'root@root.com',
  'anna@zzz.com'
];
$('input[type="radio"].st13').each(function() {
    var radio = $(this);
  var email = $(this).parent().prev('td').html();
  console.log($.inArray(email, emails));
  if ($.inArray(email, emails) != -1) {
    radio.prop('checked', true);
  }
});
```

Someone help me put this jQuery into php code, please. There are so many different solutions on Google and I have tried some solutions but not ok. I'm beginner. Please help me.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48121480/edit) your question and insert the actual PHP code. The link you've provided points towards _example.com_ and nothing else.

Comment: Your link doesn't point anywhere. If possible, can you post the relevant portion of your code directly into your question? What's the problem that you're experiencing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP files are interpreted as html files for the server. PHP code must be in php tags to work.

```
<?php ?>
```

To use javascript in a PHP file you must use script tags:

```
<script>
var emails = [
'root@root.com',
'anna@zzz.com'
];
$('input[type="radio"].st13').each(function() {
    var radio = $(this);
    var email = $(this).parent().prev('td').html();
    console.log($.inArray(email, emails));
    if ($.inArray(email, emails) != -1) {
   radio.prop('checked', true);
 }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand that JQuery and JavaScript - code that is interpreted inside of a Browser, so this code is just some text until the moment it will be inside of the Browser (Mozilla, Chrome and others).
PHP code and PHP files (in the most cases) are simple textual files that are interpreted inside of the server. Usually PHP just generates something textual, like HTML or other textual stuff and send it to the browser. Browser receive this generated text and try to understand it.

SO, your php file "index.php" can look similar to this:

```
    <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                $( document ).ready(function() {
                    var emails = [
                      'root@root.com',
                      'anna@zzz.com'
                    ];
                    $('input[type="radio"].st13').each(function() {
                      var radio = $(this);
                      var email = $(this).parent().prev('td').html();
                      console.log($.inArray(email, emails));
                      if ($.inArray(email, emails) != -1) {
                        radio.prop('checked', true);
                      }
                    });
                });
            </script>

            <?php

                echo 'This is the text generated by PHP :)';

            ?>

        </body>
    </html>
```